# How did Robert's visit to Claire's house help the plot?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-best-offer

In *The Best Offer*, why does Robert (Sturgess) manoeuvre Oldman (Rush) to take him along when he has dinner with Claire? How does this help his scheme?

Answer (score 1):

I think that's also a part of their (Robert and Claire) plan. After Robert seeing Claire, he tells to Virgil something like "Claire is more beautiful than you described and I think I like her" and Virgil replies "are you trying to make me jealous?"

Since Virgil firmly believed that Robert is expert on women's matters, I think Robert is trying to send a subliminal message to Virgil Oldman that Claire is beautiful, this will result in having Virgil to be more addictive of Claire.